# SAP Business One for Visual Studio Form Preview

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sapb1

I have created a project in SAP Business One Studio with a custom form. Too add additional functionality I created a project in Visual Studio and I try to edit my form, but it gives me:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I tried uninstall and install again SAP Business One Studio 32 bits alone, I tried with 32 and 64 bits, but I cannot open the designer in visual studio.

I check "open with" over the file NewForm and the correct editor is selected.

I do not know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem, by mistake I registered in GAC (Global Assembly Cache) some dll of SAP Business One Studio, those dll where creating problems to the form editor, but after unregister them I could start using the SAP form editor in visual studio.

Comment: I got same error. I can't any action on GAC. How do you fix it? please tell me more information about this issue

Comment: I can't remember well which dll are, if I remember well there are only 2 that cause trouble. Compare the dll that there are in wow64 with the dll used by SAP Business One Studio and unregister them with gacutil -u

Comment: Also check that you have installed .Net Framework 4.0